# Create-react-app creating App.js without Component after update

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Today i updated my node, npm and create-react-app version and now everytime i create a new app, the App.js doesn't come with Component, its just creates a function as you can see below.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

before it was

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

Did things changed in the 3.0.0 create-react-app version?

Nodejs version: v10.15.3

Npm version: 6.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `App` function is a valid React component. It is a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) as opposed to a class component in your second example.

You are correct, this change was made in `v3.0.0`: [change class component to function component](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6451)

Comment: I should use functional component or keep using statefull as before?

Comment: It's usually a personal choice. If I want to create a stateless component, I will write a functional component and If I have to maintain component level state, I will either write a class component or a functional component with `useState` hook.